# java- how to calculate sum of 2 numbers using two 2D arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have to write a program which allows the input of two numbers in two 2*3 arrays and displays the sum of the corresponding numbers. 
I am not able to understand why and how the program is to be implemented using *two* 2*3 arrays so basically I am at a lost of how it should actually be working. But still here is what I have come up so far:

```
package lesson1;
import java.util.*;

class MyClass{
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

    int sum;

    int array1[][]= new int[2][3];
    int array2[][]= new int[2][3];

    for(int i=0; i<array1.length; i++){

        for(int j=0; j<array1[i].length; j++){

            array1[i][j]= input.nextInt();

            for(int x=0; x<array2.length;x++){
                for(int y=0; y<array2.length; y++){

                    array2[x][y]= input.nextInt();

                sum= array1[i][j]+ array2[x][y];
                System.out.println("The sum is "+sum);
                }

             }

            }


        }


         }           


    }
```

Comment: You have the array2 nested for loops inside the array1 nested for loops, so array2 is being read 6 times.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, because adding two numbers is as simple as writing `a + b` so... you should probably rephrase it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that your code is too much complicated

At first you have two arrays, the array1 and the array2. That's fine but you don't need to create four "**for**"s, for that.

You can do

```
for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
     for (int y = 0; y < array1[i].length; y++ {
         array1[i][y]= input.nextInt();
         array2[i][y]= input.nextInt();
         sum = sum + array1[i][y] + array2[i][y];
     }
}
```

to fill them up and sum them.

Comment: @Dici Thanks a lot!:-) I had to sum the two elements only though like this `sum = array1[i][y] + array2[i][y];`

Comment: It's not my answer though, it's **George Coder's** one. I'm sure he will appreciate if you upvote his answer (not only accept it) so that he can reach 50 reputation and unlock some features on SO :)

Comment: @GeorgeCoder Thanks a lot for your answer! Still, I need some help in understanding how the code is really working.. like what do `array1.length` and `array2.length` really mean? `array1.length` and `array2.length` evaluate to what values?

Comment: @GeorgeCoder Doesn't `array1.length` calculates the length of only the rows?

Comment: @Dici I am still having some problem in understanding how it works. Don't `array1.length` and `array2.length` calculate the number of rows only? If so, I suppose the columns are not being considered

Comment: Yes it is the number of rows. He made a mistake in his answer, on the second line. It should be `array1[i].length`. However, `i, y` is a weird choice for array indices, I would go for `i, j` which is much more standard

Comment: @Diksha I was busy for some time but I believe that Dici covered your questions. Have fun man and anything you want ask it.